# Leaving the code in an else if() blank in order to escape the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

I'm sorry for the strange title, I couldn't find the exact wording that I wanted but I'll do my best to explain my question here. Basically I have some code that goes like this

```
if(both inputs are not null)
{
    Do this
}
else if(both inputs are null)
{

}
else if(one input is null and the other isn't)
{
    throw new Exception("Both inputs must have a value or neither should");
}
```

if I don't use the middle else if the last else if, the program will throw the exception no matter whether one or both inputs are null. I'm wanting it so that the program sees that both inputs are null and does nothing while continuing with it's execution. I'm using this data to pass to a SQl query and if one of the inputs are null it acts up. I might just be messing up the logic but I was wondering if this is considered bad practice. I can't think of a problem because there isn't a way that this could execute code accidentally. If there is a better way or if this is considered bad practice I would like to hear other ways to go about this. Thanks.

EDIT: clarified question

Comment: I've added Java language tag to your question. Edit your question and add the correct language tag. It will help code highlighting in your question, as well as in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code if the language you are using has an Exclusive OR operator. For example in C#:

```cs
string A = null;
string B = "Hello World";

if ( A != null && B != null)
{
    // Do this
}
else if ( A == null ^ B == null )
{
    throw new Exception("Both inputs must have a value or neither should");
}
```

The result of x ^ y is true if x evaluates to true and y evaluates to false, or x evaluates to false and y evaluates to true.

Comment: Wow this is actually really useful thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm missing something here. Your description doesn't seem to match your code.
In the pseudo-code you wrote, if both inputs are null, no exception should be sent, and that's what you want. But you are saying the exception is still sent ? Something is up here. Can you post something closer to your actual code ?
What you describe seems closer to the behavior of a `switch case`, where an empty "case" would just drop to the next one.

Both diregarding that, you can avoid those empty "else if" by re-ordering your tests :

```
if(both inputs are not null)
{
    Do this
}
else if(one input is null and the other isn't)
{
     throw new Exception("Both inputs must have a value or neither should");
}
```

This way, no need for an additional empty `else if`.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. What I was meaning to say was that if I do not include that middle empty else if it would throw the exception. With the empty else if it simple skips the last else if and goes on with the execution. I was wondering if this is considered as a bad habit and if so a way to go around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix, in my opinion, would be to change your code to below

```
if(both inputs are not null)
{
    Do this
}
else if((input1==null && input2!=null) || (input1!=null && input2==null))
{
    throw new Exception("Both inputs must have a value or neither should");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor out this logic in its own method, and then write it as following:

```
private void refactoredMethod(Input i1, Input i2) {
    //Do nothing if both inputs are null.
    if (i1 == null && i2 == null)
        return;

    //Throw if either of them is null.
    if (input1 == null || input2 == null)
        throw ...

    //Neither input is null, do the normal processing.
    //so, "Do this"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not checking if either one of the inputs is null?
Then you could throw an exception and continue afterwards if no exception was thrown.

So something like this (in java terms):

```java
if(firstInput == null || secondInput == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must not be null");
}

// do what you want afterwards
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `||`? I don't know Java.

Comment: I chose not to use this because I want the program not to care if both inputs are null while throwing the exception when only one of the inputs are null. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**How about this:**

```
bool A = (input1 == null), B = (input2 == null);
if (A != B) {
    throw new Exception("Both inputs must have a value or neither should");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that source code is sometimes better readable with empty blocks for certain conditions. I assume this is what you want to do. Example:

```
if(street!=null && zip!=null)
{
    storeAddress(street,zip);
}
else if(street==null && zip==null)
{
    ; // Do nothing
}
else // only one of street or zip was provided
{
    throw new Exception("Street and zip code must be filled together or both left empty");
}
```

I use the semicolon here to avoid warnings from SpotBugs. This way I tell Spotbugs (and other developers), that the block is empty on purpose.

The last condition of your example is redundant, so I turned it into a comment.

Comment: Just to clarify leaving this middle else if blank is not harmful? I don't see a problem with creating this statement like this but at the same time it looks wrong. I'm mostly worrying about best practice because I know that it doesn't cause issues on my code.

Comment: No, it is harmless. The Java language allows empty blocks. I wont think too much about best pratise. If it works and the intention is clear, then why not?